# Getting error unable to author blocks while starting blockchain

Tags: polkadot, kusama, blockchain

I am building a blockchain using substrate framework and after adding the required pallets, and compiling them successfully getting a runtime error `Unable to author block in slot 413737816,. can_author_with returned: spec_name does not match node vs Test Probably a node update is required!`, i was trying to solve this issue and bumped to [this github issue](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/issues/731)  but was still not able to resolve the error, i am attaching the screenshot of the error, can someone help me with this.[image: runtime error]

Comment: Can you check your configuration inside chain_spec.rs i think, And also you can try to search for that method can_author_with

Comment: @MrishoLukamba i checked chain_spec.rs and also can_author_with method but was not able to diagnose anything

Comment: Okey can you maybe try to run your own private network using Alice and bob as predefined validators, follow the private network tutorial, and see if that problem still persists

Comment: @MrishoLukamba tried to run private network but still getting same issue

Comment: I really dont have full context of the issue. Is it a new fresh template?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, please provide an answer :)